# RTC-Websphere not starting up

Tags: java, websphere

i am using websphere and i have created few projects. But my websphere is not starting up from today mng. I am getting the progress dialog box with Progress Information. But it is not closing. I think may be last time it was not closed properly or some progress was not completed.

I am getting error as below when i closed the websphere through task manager,

```
Java was started but returned the error code = 1073807364
```

Please help to resolve this issue. I am hanging with these issue and unable to proceed with my tasks.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Error indicates that Websphere or RAD is not loading JDK correctly. Check for the correct JDK path in configuration file.